# Linux on my chromebook just broke - why?

Tags: xfce, chromium, chromebook, crouton

I have a chromebook that I dual-boot linux on via crouton. I was flipping back and forth between chromium and linux using the keyboard shortcut, and it just randomly stopped working. I tried rebooting linux by closing out of the chromium command line and trying to start it again, but it just produced:

```
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/xenial...
/usr/bin/startxfce4: Starting X server

_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 4.4.118-13212-g6c21f415c5d1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon May 14 23:16:44 PDT 2018 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 3584000 verity payload=PARTUUID=a426f256-534d-ba40-a9b8-ed38fc20733b/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=a426f256-534d-ba40-a9b8-ed38fc20733b/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=3584000 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=2beeb95eb41112a3c3fa7a2386b67943bde847e7 salt=a5efca76297948a7369778adc0e1e0bd7e02b87785c22a2847abcbc7363ab718" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=a426f256-534d-ba40-a9b8-ed38fc20733b add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic
Build Date: 13 October 2017  01:57:05PM
xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.5.log", Time: Thu Jun  7 22:28:15 2018
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
```

And didn't actually work. When Linux crashed I was programming in Python 3, but I don't think I was actually running a program. I also had notepad up. I have done all of these things before with no problems. The only troubles I've had with crouton in the past is when the chromebook automatically restarts to update chromium linux usually breaks, but that hasn't happened either.

How can I fix my Linux dual-boot, and why did this happen?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

### Edit based upon answer:

Checking permissions produced

```
total 0
srwxrwxrwx 1 chronos chronos 0 Jun  5 10:22 X1
srwxrwxrwx 1 chronos chronos 0 Jun  7 18:44 X2
srwxrwxrwx 1 chronos chronos 0 Jun  7 18:48 X3
srwxrwxrwx 1 chronos chronos 0 Jun  7 18:53 X4
srwxrwxrwx 1 chronos chronos 0 Jun  7 22:28 X5
```

I ran `chown root:root /tmp/.X11-unix` and it said `chown: changing ownership of '/tmp/.X11-unix': Operation not permitted`, so I ran again using sudo, which produced no errors, then checked the file permissions again, which produced the same result as before.

### Update:

Changed permissions on file successfully as per answer; ran `sudo startxfce4` again; didn't work and produced the following:

```
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/xenial...
/usr/bin/startxfce4: Starting X server


X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 4.4.118-13212-g6c21f415c5d1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon May 14 23:16:44 PDT 2018 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 3584000 verity payload=PARTUUID=a426f256-534d-ba40-a9b8-ed38fc20733b/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=a426f256-534d-ba40-a9b8-ed38fc20733b/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=3584000 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=2beeb95eb41112a3c3fa7a2386b67943bde847e7 salt=a5efca76297948a7369778adc0e1e0bd7e02b87785c22a2847abcbc7363ab718" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=a426f256-534d-ba40-a9b8-ed38fc20733b add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic  
Build Date: 13 October 2017  01:57:05PM
xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.7.log", Time: Fri Jun  8 10:12:14 2018
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
```

### Update 2:

I restarted the whole laptop again and now it works properly. I'll be filing a bug report as an answer suggested. If anyone has any clues as to why this happened or if there's anything I should do to prevent it happening again, that'd be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root`

Change the permissions of that file to "root". But do check what the permissions are and report it as a bug.

Also take note of`Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.5.log"`. That will hold extra information on the problem.

Checking permissions:

```
ls -l /tmp/.X11-unix
```

Changing permissions:

```
sudo chown -R root:root /tmp/.X11-unix
```

You can use a live session, grub rescue or the current system through a tty if it is only the desktop that crashes.

Comment: Please take a look at the edit to my answer; this didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: Try `chown -f` as sudo. the `-f` flag forces the change and doesn't report ownership.

Comment: Is .X11-unix a dir perhaps? edit made to reflect this.

Comment: @Rinzwind I ran `sudo chown -R` and checked permissions and it now shows it as root, but then I ran `sudo startxfce4` again and it didn't work. I updated the answer with the new result.